# How to use noteblockapi bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Hey I am trying to make a minecraft plugin so when a player joins it plays that custom sound.

I have looked into some stuff such as noteblockapi and was wondering if anyone could help me on how I could get it to play this custom .nbs

```
    @EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin()
{

    //Player.playSound(file.nbs)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [NoteblockAPI to play songs](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/noteblockapi.19287/)

```
Song s = NBSDecoder.parse(new File(getDataFolder(), "Song.nbs"));
SongPlayer sp = new RadioSongPlayer(s);
sp.setAutoDestroy(true);
sp.addPlayer(e.getPlayer());
sp.setPlaying(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [the API reference](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/NoteBlock.html), you want this method:

```
play​(Instrument instrument, Note note)
```

Where `Instrument` and `Note` are both enums in the `org.bukkit` package.

So you need to create a BlockState of the Noteblock, cast it to the `NoteBlock` interface, and call `.play` on it.  Probably something like this:

```
((NoteBlock)Material.NOTE_BLOCK).play(Instrument.BELL, Note.Tone.A);
```

Replace the instrument and tone as desired.

Comment: Hey if I already have a .nbs sound file is there a way I could add that instead of playing every note separately?

Comment: @coolio85 No idea. I have never used Bukkit, but I do know how to read the documentation.

Comment: Hey @Draco18snolongertrustsSE the OP was talking about a different API.